# Big Oh Notation Confusion

Tags: complexity-theory, big-o

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my understanding but this aspect of Big Oh notation seems strange to me.  Say you have two algorithms - the first preforms n^2 operations and the second performs n^2-n operations.  Because of the dominance of the quadratic term, both algorithms would have complexity O(n^2), yet the second algorithm will always be better than the first.  That seems weird to me, Big Oh notation makes it seem like they are same.  I dunno...

Comment: Look at the graphs of `y = x²` and `y = x² - x`, as `x` gets really, _really,_ ***REALLY*** big.

Comment: They are "the same" in the sense that they are both better than, say, O(n) (e.g. 10000*n) and worse than, say, O(n^3) (e.g. .0001*n^3) when n gets large enough. That is all "big-O" is trying to capture.

Comment: Hypothetically, say you were asked to provide an algorithm that does better than O(n^2).  I guess the n^2-n algorithm would not be correct then, even though it does better than n^2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Big O is not about the time it takes to execute your algorithm, it is about how well it will scale when presented with large data sets (large values of n).

When presented with a large data set, the n^2 term will quickly overshadow any linear term.  So the linear term becomes insignificant.

Answer (score 1):

When n grows towards infinity n^2 will be much greater then n so the -n won't have any significant difference on the outcome.